# LDAP an error occured while performing the search

Tags: active-directory, ldap

After I input this in the windows explorer:ldap://domain:port as expected a new window opens with find people. But every time I enter the username it will say **an error occured while performing the search**.

[image: Click to view]

Comment: Are you using LDP tool? Can you tell how're you getting this error message? It looks the problem is in the anonymous binding as discussed in the answer written by T-Heron.

Comment: I don't think this question should have been put on Hold.  It had to do with a programming question/tool.   The answer included a great diagnostic tool - WireShark - and included an example of LDAP debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, anonymous binds to Active Directory are not allowed.  That *Find People* dialog you brought up is a legacy tool meant for searching people in external directories, not in Active Directory, and won't work even if the computer is joined to the AD domain.  As a test, I just tried it the same way you did and it also failed with the exact same error message.  I analyzed that error inside of a WireShark trace (see image below) and confirmed my suspicion:  when you brought up that dialog, AD ignored your request because it considered it to be an anonymous bind. You won't be able to bind successfully using that tool in any way. Instead, run the Active Directory Users and Computers tool to search for users in the AD domain - that will work natively.  Your computer must be joined to the AD domain in order to do all this.[image]